# Magento 1.9 Wysiwyg image URL problems on Product pages

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.9.1

I am try to set multiple Images in attribute using Wysiwyg Editor and try to get those images in product detail page but no success. and in view source I get something like this `<img alt="" lighthouse.jpg"}}"="" productfeed="" wysiwyg="" src="{{media url=">` so may be it will not allow me to get path in this format {{media url="lighthouse.jpg"}}. So how to get images which i have uploaded using Wysiwyg Editor on product page.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally I got solution,

If you are also facing same issue than use

> $this->helper('cms')->getBlockTemplateProcessor()->filter($this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($this->getProduct(),nl2br($_description), 'description') )

Instead of

> $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($this->getProduct(),nl2br($_description),
>   'description')

where you want to show product description or any attribute along with it's images which you uploaded using Wysiwyg editor. for further detail go through this [link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/210263/)

Comment: This is the problem I have but unfortunately your solution is pretty vague. Where is this call made? what file?